# What is cb() in Node?

Tags: node.js

Where are people getting cb() from, is this a Node thing or vanilla JS thing?

For example:

[Managing Node.js Callback Hell with Promises, Generators and Other Approaches](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-callback-hell-promises-generators/)

they're using cb() to I guess callback and return an error or a value or both in some cases depending on what the callback function sig is?

Comment: it'll be hard for me to declare a winner, you all gave great answers and it really saved me research time and helped me a ton...thanks!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`cb` in the context you're describing it is how a vanilla callback function is passed into a (typically) asynchronous function, which is a common pattern in node.js (it's sometimes labelled next, but you can call it `bananas` if you so desire - it's just an argument).

Typically the first argument is an `error` object (often false - if all went as planned) and subsequent arguments are data of some form.

For example:

```
function myAsyncFunction(arg1, arg2, cb) {
    // async things
    cb(false, { data: 123 });
}
```

then using this function:

```
myAsyncFunction(10, 99, function onComplete(error, data) {
    if (!error) {
        // hooray, everything went as planned
    } else {
        // disaster - retry / respond with an error etc
    }
});
```

Promises are an alternative to this design pattern where you would return a [Promise object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) from `myAsyncFunction`

For example:

```
function myAsyncFunction2(arg1, arg2) {
    return new Promise(function resolution(resolve, reject, {
        // async things
        resolve({ data: 123 });
    });
}
```

then using this function:

```
myAsyncFunction2(10, 99)
    .then(function onSuccess(data) {
        // success - send a 200 code etc
    })
    .catch(function onError(error) {
        // oh noes - 500
    });
```

They're basically the same thing, just written slightly differently. Promises [aren't supported especially widely](http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises) in a native form, but if put through a transpiler (I'd recommend [babel](https://babeljs.io/)) during a build step they should perform reliably enough in a browser too.

Callbacks will always work in a browser with no shimming / transpilation.

Comment: as a caller of that function how would I know what the internal callback function sig is that as a caller I'd need to know how to specify so I can handle the callback?  So if I'm looking at a function I wanna call and only see function myAsyncFunction(arg1, arg2, cb)  and you're defining inside myAsyncFunction cb's sig to be a bool and an object, I wouldn't know unless I was forced to look at the internal implemenation of myAsyncFunction as a caller...that seems to go agains developer discoverability

Comment: it's like going to a library like jQuery and unless they've documented what their internal callback sigs are for you to tall x function, you wouldn't know other than having to literally dive into the core jquery source to find out.

Comment: Yeah that's a totally fair observation and I'm pretty sure the answer here is just "it's a convention: use (error, data) as your callback sig"

Comment: gotcha, so you just have to read the docs in the case of libraries OR there are just some defacto known conventions that you become aware of as a Noder.

Comment: what about the case with gulp and other frameworks or libraries where they just do a cb() inside the function?  No params at all.

Comment: yea I'm using babel right now and starting to learn and use generators.  Like Koa uses generators and I'm using koa for REST.

Comment: Yeah a bit of both. In my experience rarely has this been an issue. Often libraries are flexible about where you might want to pass in your callback, e.g. `fn(arg1, optionalArg2, cb)` can be called as `fn(10, function(...))` if `optionalArg2` isn't relevant to your particular needs. However the return side (how the callback is provided), should always be a consistent (error, data) callback

Comment: in the case of gulp I think they have some other signatures, e.g. `fn(filename, buffer)` maybe. I'd say that sometimes giving cb a more intuitive name (e.g. "operationComplete") can help with confusion, which I _think_ might be the use case you're referring to in gulp.

Comment: ok that might explain it, a fellow dev on our web team (I'm backend) uses cb() in his gulp file, probably means "done"

Comment: Yeah I'm all for excessively verbose function names to avoid this sort of confusion, it probably means done.

Comment: Thank you, very nice explanation! Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: so `cb` is just short for callback, and can be replaced with any other variable names?

Comment: I wonder how it got so many upvotes without even answering the op question. cb is callback okay, but _where is cb defined or coming from?_

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari cb is defined in function defintion: `function myAsyncFunction(arg1, arg2, cb) {` <= here.

Answer (score 2):

node.js has lots of asynchronous operations that take a completion callback as an argument.  This is very common in various node.js APIs.

The node.js convention for this callback is that the first argument passed to the callback is an error code.  A falsey value for this first argument means that there is no error.

For example:

```
fs.readFile("test.txt", function(err, data) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("file data is: " + data);
    }
});
```

A function you create yourself may also define it's own callback in order to communicate the end of one or more asynchronous operations.

```
function getData(id, cb) {
    var fname = "datafile-" + id + ".txt";
    fs.readFile(fname, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            cb(err);
        } else if (data.slice(0, 6) !== "Header"){
            // proper header not found at beginning of file data
            cb(new Error("Invalid header"));
        } else {
            cb(0, data);
        }
    });
}

// usage:
getData(29, function(err, data) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: I see so the callback could be a param but you define the callback's own params when you actually callback with the values as params.  Meaning, in the first sig, there is (id, cb) Then you actually callback with the values (0, data) so cb is just a param that points to really cb(0,data) in reality?

Comment: I see so this is for example how jQuery functions define what kind of function callback you can expect as the caller of that function

Comment: @WeDoTDD - I don't understand your recent comment.  Are you asking some additional question?  Callbacks can be defined with any arguments that caller wants to pass to the callback.

Comment: yes I am.  So let me get this straight.  Your first code example is in the view of the caller...in that they're specifying an anonymous function for the function being called to call back on.  In your second example, you're the function being called and dictating the type of function sig (callback sig) that you will send back to the caller (for example like a jquery control, it would define its own callback function internally and then clients need to know what that is so that they are able to get that callback and handle it)

Comment: When you pass a callback function as an argument, you're just passing a function reference that will be called later by the function you are calling.  you must define that function reference to have the arguments that the caller will pass.

Comment: @WeDoTDD - yes, I've shown examples both ways - passing a callback to an existing function that accepts a callback argument and defining your own function that accepts a callback function as an argument.

Comment: "node.js has lots of asynchronous operations that take a completion callback as an argument. This is very common in various node.js APIs."  But isn't that also just vanilla javascript meaning you can send in a callback function, it's not a "Node" thing?

Comment: I have looked up falsely and I still don't understand the damn thing...same for truthy.

Comment: for now the way I've been providing values in functions I create as callbacks is with a single param like this: function find(someId, data){ ...some code then data(foundData);}  Then the caller obviously called it like this:  find(10, function(data){ ..do something with the found data{);  I just haven't done a lot of defining callbacks within a function but definitely will be now for sure...once I start introducing error handling into my code.

Comment: I had to go with jfriend because he really covered all scenarios of callbacks including promises which I'm just starting to get more familiar with.  I wish I could use both your replies as a complete answer TBH, both equality with great info.  Thanks!

Comment: "Callbacks can be defined with any arguments that caller wants to pass to the callback".  Are you saying you could have a situation where the caller passes in a specified signature and somehow your function needs to know how to dynamically handle the args which really could be anything the caller defines?  How would that work even?  if I'm a function where the caller defines the callback my function should return with, my function could anticipate any sort of argument types or # of args, or am I way off base here?

Comment: @WeDoTDD - for a callback to be useful, the caller has to specify what the arguments will be so the code passing in the callback knows how to treat the arguments.  That has to be known ahead of time.  It is usually specified in documentation or can be discerned by examining the code.

Comment: Got it just did not see that page, explains it well

Answer (score -1):

From the Vanilla JS, you can declare a function and pass throuw parameters a declaration of another function, that can called async

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

Comment: dead link, and doesn't explain what is cb()

Comment: Updated with the proper link :D